# HTTP response returning status 0 when adding filemimetype validator to Zf2 form

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2, mime-types

I had an error when i add filemimetype validator to my validator chain in one of my forms. I got an http status 0 and there aren't messages on Apache 2 logs. Does someone have an idea about what's happening? Here is the code:

```
$fileInput->getValidatorChain()
->attachByName('filesize', ['max' => 1440000], false)
// when i uncomment the following line and send the form the described error occurs
//->attachByName('filemimetype', ['mimeType' => 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/x-png,image/jpg,image/gif'], true)
;
```

Additionally **FileInfo** extension is enabled according to my php_info() output, what means it should have been used by filemimetype validator (see [mime type validator zf2 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.file.mime-type.html)).

Comment: ->attachByName('filemimetype',  array('mimeType' => 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/x-png,image/jpg,image/gif')) can you please remove last params and try this it worked for me

Comment: @kamlesh.bar i've just copied yout statement and i still got the same error. I think it is a zf2 problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had similar issues with uploading files and mime type checking on OS X. 
Setting the following options to the mime type validator:

```
->attachByName(
    'filemimetype',
    [
        // this is optional and not necessary, falls back to HTTP informations of uploaded file if mime type cannot be resolved
        // 'enableHeaderCheck' => true,
        'magicFile' => false,
        'mimeType' => [
            'image/jpg',
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/png',
        ]
    ]
);
```

See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6493 and http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.file.mime-type.html

cheers